# For each element $x$ of group $H$ let $F(x) = \{ h \in H :hxh^{-1} = x\}$ For any $d\in H$, prove the equality $F(d) = F(d^{-1})$

Tags: group-theory

For each element $x$ of group $H$ let $F(x) = \{h \in H :hxh^{-1} = x\}$.

For any element $d$ of $H$, prove the equality $F(d) = F(d^{-1})$

I'm a little confused here and not exactly sure what is being asked.

1. For "any element d of $H$" we are just saying some subset $H$. Meaning just find a element of d where $F(d) = F(d^{-1})$ is true?
2. I feel like this is a subset question, but there is no mention of that. Should I consider $F(x)$ a subgroup, meaning as long as $F(something)$ is true that is a subgroup? Or is $F$ just a mapping that applies to all a $\in H$.
3. The only thing that I can think of works is something very trivial. Like:

Well if  $F(x) = \{h \in H :hxh^{-1} = x\}$, where $h=e$ then we would have $exe^{-1}=x$ 
For the case of $F(d) = F(d^{-1})$ then if $d=e$ then $F(e)=F(e^{-1}) \rightarrow heh^{-1}=he^{-1}h^{-1}\rightarrow e=e$

I think I missing something much more fundemtal here and in the total wrong direction.

Comment: This is another confusing use of the word "any" which should really be banned from use in formal mathematics. The intended meaning is "Prove that $F(d) = F(d^{-1})$ for all $d \in H$". But if this were an exam that I was grading, then I would feel compelled to give your answer full marks, because your interpretation of the question is linguistically valid.

Comment: By the way $F(d)$ is a subgroup of $H$ called the *centralizer of $d$ in $H$*, and is ususally denoted by $C_H(d)$.

Answer (score 4):

Since

$$\begin{align}
(hxh^{-1})^{-1}&=(h^{-1})^{-1}x^{-1}h^{-1}\\
&=hx^{-1}h^{-1},
\end{align}$$

we have,

$$hx^{-1}h^{-1}=x^{-1}.$$

Hence $F(x)\subseteq F(x^{-1})$.

Now simply let $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ in the above and you'll find the same argument holds. Hence $F(x^{-1})\subseteq F(x)$.

Hence $F(x^{-1})=F(x)$.

---

Note that $x$ is arbitrary, so the conclusion is what the question intended. The use of "for any" should be read as synonymous with "for all".

Comment: But the OP was asking for an explanation of the meaning of the question rather than for an answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt. I have edited my answer. Is it any better?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asked to prove is that the set equation $F(d)=F(d^{-1})$ does hold *for all* $d\in H$. So, if you can prove the equality of the two sets without any specific assumption on $d$ (*e.g.* "$d=e$" etc.), then you are done. For instance as follows:

Since in a group elements' inverses are unique, we get $x=y\iff x^{-1}=y^{-1}$. Therefore:
\begin{alignat}{1}
F(d) &= \{h \in H \mid hdh^{-1} = d\} \\
&= \{h \in H \mid (hdh^{-1})^{-1} = d^{-1}\} \\
&= \{h \in H \mid hd^{-1}h^{-1} = d^{-1}\} \\
&= F(d^{-1})
\end{alignat}

Comment: But the OP was asking for an explanation of the meaning of the question rather than for an answer to the question

Comment: I've edited. Hope now it better addresses OP's question, @DerekHolt